# How to train a network for a better performance?

Tags: neural-network

I have a 10 by 57300 matrix as an input, and a 1 by 57300 matrix as an output that only includes 0 and 1.I tried to train neural network with feed-forward back propagation and layer recurrent back propagation structures. I tried those structures with one hidden layer and 40 neurons in hidden layer.In the best case the performance stopped at point 0.133. I simulated the network with new inputs but it did not give me the result that I wanted. And the results were not even close to what I trained the network with. Do you have any suggestion to improve the performance of the network?

```
inputs = input;
targets = output;

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 50;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};


% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';

net.divideParam.trainInd=1:28650;  % The first 94 inputs are for training.
net.divideParam.valInd=28651:42977;    % The first 94 inputs are for validation.
net.divideParam.testInd=42978:57300; % The last 5 inputs are for testing the network.

% For help on training function 'trainlm' type: help trainlm
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt

% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean squared error

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};


% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs)

% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, plotfit(net,inputs,targets)
%figure, plotregression(targets,outputs)
%figure, ploterrhist(errors)
```

This is the code that I used for training neural network. My 57300 input divides to 300X191 groups of data. I mean each set of input is a 10 by 191 group. So that's why I've used "divideind". I have normalized the input and output matrix in [-1 1] range because I use tansig transfer function. But I still do not get the result that I want form the network.

Comment: You might want to try posting this question on another stackexchange site like [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com) or [Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com); those sites are a bit more focused on the performance of data models.

Answer (score 1):

it is usually complicate to tell how to improve a network with such few information. In some cases a performance of 0.133 could be a good result, in others not so much. Nonetheless, general ideas to improve networks could be normalizing the inputs to [0,1] range, performing feature selection, maybe adding a rbm layer and performing non-supervised training before the supervised backpropagation learning scheme (see Deep belief networks), increasing the data for learning, or using cross-validation for choosing the free parameters and to early stop.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. Second, I have edited my question, and I hope it gives more detail about what I'm doing.

Comment: As I said look for ways of performing feature extraction before training the network. If you are not too comfortable with this change for deep learning as it provides a first non-supervised followed by supervised training. here is one possible software. http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/42853-deep-neural-network

Answer (score 1):

**Edit v1:**

I see that you have 94 inputs for testing, 94 for validation and 5 for testing. This ratio seems a bit error prone.

First of all, 94 input sets for a feature vector of 10 is very few. For a feature vector of 100 is futile :). So basically the problem is that you don't have enough data to train 40 neurons. If you can't generate more data, i'd recommend a new splitting:

150 Training
10 Validation
30 Testing

---

This information is rather more general approach to improve NN performance:

**The training methodology**

How many epochs? It is possible that the network is **over-trained to your input set**.
Parameters of the BP algorithm (momentum, adaptation factors, etc.)

**The feature extraction algorithm**

Often, this is the main problem. The algorithm is not able to really *extract the specific features* of an input.

I suggest plotting all the inputs visually and see if you are seeing any pattern and are able to determine the separation visually. After all, the neural network is a bit more complex statistic system.

Good luck!

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. Second, I have edited my question, and I hope it gives more detail about what I'm doing.

Comment: as suggested change your ratios of training, validation and testing. Further, use the validation points to optimize the free parameters. Finally, perform feature extraction as suggested to decrease the length of the input vector, as this is probably your major problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you are training your network for classification purpose or regression. But if you directly want to improve the performance I will suggest you to do following things :

1- Increase the number of nodes in the hidden layer further. Try out something bigger to see if the neural network is doing  better(it may be because of overtraining, but ignore it for now).

2- If their is very high non-linearity in the data space then add one more hidden layer. But adding many of them will not work in the case of simple neural network.

Comment: first, thanks for your answer. Second, I have edited my question, and I hope it gives more detail about what I'm doing.

Comment: Sorry but this is not a good answer. Increasing the number of nodes in the hidden layer, or number of layers without proper care may lead to overfitting of the data which is not desired. In fact what distinguish a good from a bad network is proper regularization, which attempts to generalize the learning to new unseen inputs. Additionally, the increase of nodes lead to degradation of the backpropagation algorithm, leading to a slower convergence.